# Custom Share Function - how could an app use the same login instance used by another app on a user's device

Tags: android, ios, share, facebook-messenger

Is there a way that an iOS and/or Android App can take advantage of the fact that a user is already logged in to Messenger on their device.

Take a custom share function. Instead of using the native share functionality of Android and iOS (Not good enough for the requirements of my app) a custom one exists that, after some criteria are interpreted by this app's api, loads the effective web version of the Messenger app overlayed on my app pretty much as a web view or effective iFrame in web vernacular.

However, it will load the login screen of messenger as the local browser of my app displayed through the web viewer is not logged into Messenger. The owner of the device is however logged into messenger on their phone or tablet via the messenger App.

The objective is that they do not have to log in again separately on this app and can proceed straight to the effective share screen of the web version of messenger.

To do this, the app would have to know that the user was already logged in on this device and use the same session instance (I presume). Is that possible?

If it is not possible, how does the native iOS share screen of Apple's own Apps (take Safari as an example) show the relevant share page of messenger without having to open the app? The same is true for other share options. Whilst many of these are Apple's own (Mail etc..), others are not including Messenger and LinkedIN.

PS.. forgive the use of the phrase "My App", this was simply to avoid confusion over whether Messenger or not was being referred to.